# How to change a RealmList to RealmResult?

Tags: java, android, realm

I am building a Java android app and I am using realm.io for my database. My problem is I have a RealmList and my Custom ListView adapter only accepts RealmResults. Below is the code and more details.

I have an Chat class that has a RealmList, RealmList, userId and a chatId.

```
public class Chat extends RealmObject{

private RealmList<Friend> participants;
private RealmList<Message> messages;

@PrimaryKey
private String chatId;
private String userId;

...
}
```

In my activity where I am trying to display all the messages that the chat has, I can call chat.getMessages() to get all the messages for this chat as a RealmList but my ListView adapter below takes a RealmResult because it extends RealmBaseAdapter

```
public class MessageAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<Message> implements ListAdapter {

private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();

public MessageAdapter(Context context,
                   RealmResults<Message> realmResults,
                   boolean automaticUpdate) {
    super(context, realmResults, automaticUpdate);
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_message, parent, false);
    }

    Message message = getRealmResults().get(position);

    if (message != null)
    {
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_content)).setText(message.getContent());
        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.CANADA);
        ((TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.message_time)).setText(dateFormat.format(message.getTimestamp()));
    }

    return convertView;
}

public RealmResults<Message> getRealmResults() {
    return realmResults;
}
}
```

Here is where I call it all

```
RealmList<Message> messages = chat.getMessages();

    ListView messageList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.message_list);
    adapter = new MessageAdapter(this, messages, true);
    messageList.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I am open to changing my RealmList to a RealmResult if possible (I have looked and it doesn't seem to be) or If I can use a RealmList in the custom realm adapter that would another solution. Anything to help me move forward would be great help.

thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do

```
chat.getMessages().where().findAll()
```

(Answer from [here](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/1952))

Answer (score 1):

RealmBaseAdapter has a very simple [implementation](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java).

So in the case, you can pass the specific `Chat` to you adapter, and overload below methods:

```java
@Override
public int getCount() {
    if (realmResults == null || realmResults.size() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    return realmResults.first().getMessages().size();
}

@Override
public T getItem(int i) {
    if (realmResults == null || realmResults.size() == 0) {
        return null;
    }
    return realmResults.first().getMessages().get(i);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
// You message view here
}
```

Comment: Doing this, does it manage automaticUpdate for object in relation?

Comment: Yes, it does. When the object in relation changes, the changeListener will be triggered as well. And `RealmBaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged` will be called.

Comment: what does `T` represents ? because i am getting incompatible return type error

Comment: @Hunt See https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/realm/realm-library/src/main/java/io/realm/RealmBaseAdapter.java#L34 for the `T`

Comment: ok , the issue i am facing is my adapter class is as `public class CompensationProductAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<CompensationList> ` and when i am overriding `getItem` by using `@Override
    public CompensationProductsList getItem(int i) {
        if (compensationList == null || compensationList.size() == 0) {
            return null;
        }
        return compensationList.first().getCompensationProductsLists().get(i);
    }
` i am getting incompatible error

Comment: if we take above example then if i create adapter for `Chat` then i will get error in `getItem`'s implementation as i am returning `Message` from that function

Comment: @Hunt `@Override public CompensationList getItem(int i)` instead of  `@Override public CompensationProductsList getItem(int i)` if `public class CompensationProductAdapter extends RealmBaseAdapter<CompensationList>` . Try to use Android Studio's auto-completion to make you life easier :)

Comment: But I want to use CompensationProductList but my realsm reasult is CompensationList. CompensationList has CompensationProductList inside tht

Comment: @Hunt Then you can just not extend the `RealmBaseAdapter`, write your own instead. If you check the implementation of `RealmBaseAdapter` you will find it is actually very simple.